# Why is scrolling interacting badly with my webscraping?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, click

I'm trying to scrape all the corner betting odds for a given game at skybet, but it looks like scrolling is messing things up in my loop. When I print section.text it looks like its doing what I want but then it clicks the wrong thing?
And when I don't scroll it will only click on the first few odds sections before the code just freezes.
Any help would be really appreciated thanks!

Also, I made the odds_sections refresh itself at each iteration because I thought that might be the problem.

```
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get("https://m.skybet.com/football/competitions")
driver.maximize_window()

#click accept cookie
try:
    button_cookie = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//body/div[2]/div[1]/a[2]"))
        )
    button_cookie.click()
except:
    print("no cookie")

#find location of premier league     
pl = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("split__title")
locate_pl=0
link_name = pl[locate_pl].text
while link_name != "Premier League":
    locate_pl += 1
    link_name = pl[locate_pl].text

pl[locate_pl].click()    
N = locate_pl + 1
#use N now to find pl matches
time.sleep(2)


#click on first match 
button_match = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='competitions']/ul[1]/li[{}]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/a[1]".format(N))
teams = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='competitions']/ul[1]/li[{}]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/a[1]/b/span".format(N))
button_match.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)  
time.sleep(2)

#find and click corners button
try:
    button_corners = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"_1ouz2ki")))
#button_corners = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_1ouz2ki")
except:
    print("no corners")
n=0
link_name = button_corners[n].text
while link_name != "Corners":
    n += 1
    link_name = button_corners[n].text

button_corners[n].click()

#Now we will scrape all corner odds for this game.
odds_sections = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_t0tx82')
N_sections = len(odds_sections)
c=0
scroll_to = 35
#the issue is within this loop
while c <= N_sections:
    
    odds_sections = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_t0tx82')
    section = odds_sections[c]

    print(section.text)
    section.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    section.click()
    c += 1
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,{})".format(scroll_to))
```

Comment: I cannot open that website as it says it doesn't exist for me, maybe because of country restrictions but i guess your error is to increase the scroll in every iteration by 35 instead of just scrolling 35 pixels. `scroll_to += 35` should be `scroll_to = 35` if you want so scroll always the same distance

Comment: Yep you're right, I did actually want to scroll the same distance each time. It's not fixing the issue though.   Have edited the code.

Comment: is there any output to your console you can post here?

Comment: the DOM could be updating after or during getting your odds_sections array (it could be in process of updating or updating after .click() or after scroll... )  try/catch exceptions for your .text, and .click() calls to check.  You'll see a "stale element" exception if that is the case.  (So grab elements again...) Remember this is an array of webelements, which is a collection of references to the DOM.  It's kind of like having a bunch of pointers pointing to memory that is changing.